# Multi dimentional array printing in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm kind of new to Java programming and I know how to basically print an array using java. But, what I currently need is little bit complex for my level. I searched for a help and examples are not helping to get what I wanted.

Here is what I need.

I need to give the following input.

```
int[][] array = { 
              {100, 12 , 0, 3},
              {100, 177, 0, 3},
              {100, 233, 0, 3}, 
              {100, 144242, 0, 3},
              {100, 14, 0, 4},  
              {100, 12234, 0, 4},
              {100, 134, 1, 4},
              {2, 15, 0, 3},
              {23, 1533, 0, 3},
              {23, 1322, 1, 4}, 
              {23, 13, 1, 4}, 
              {23, 122, 1, 4},
              {1321, 142, 1, 4},
              {1321, 133,1, 4},
              {3, 16, 0, 5},
              {55, 1003, 0,3},
              {553, 1002, 2, 6},
              {31, 162, 0, 5},
              {7, 1626, 0, 5},
              {7, 2336, 0,5}           
             };
```

And I need to get the following output.

```
100 { 
    0{
       3{177,233,144242,12},
       4{14,12234}
    },
    1{
        3{}
        4{134}
    }
       ------------------
}
```

Comment: Have you made any effort to learn about multi dimensional array from net? If yes, then please share what is the problem faced by you? Is it related to understanding or something else?

Comment: Why don't you use your own pojo to store data instead of storing it in multi-dimension array.

Comment: Is there any relation between the input and output? I can't see any.

Comment: What happened to the 12 from the first array?  Or rather, while it's very nice that you gave an example, I think it'd be highly appropriate to expound upon what it is you want to do exactly.  (It crossed my mind to facetiously just answer with one println() with your desired output....:)

Comment: Modified the question. Can you please look at it?

Comment: Why isn't 12 in the third line. eg. 3{12, 177, 233, 144242}?

Comment: How would you know to include the blank line on line 7?

Comment: @matt , oh! yeah! 12 must be there. Modified the answer and , I just left it blank, because there's nothing i can put there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this. This will help.

```
public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //pax(p) = Single, Double, Triple
    //p1=0 , p2=1, p3=2

    //basis(b) = RO, BB, HB, FB
    //b1=3 , b2=4 , b3=5 , b4=6

    int[][] array = { 
              {100, 12 , 0, 3},
              {100, 177, 0, 3},
              {100, 233, 0, 3}, 
              {100, 144242, 0, 3},
              {100, 14, 0, 4},  
              {100, 12234, 0, 4},
              {100, 134, 1, 4},
              {2, 15, 0, 3},
              {23, 1533, 0, 3},
              {23, 1322, 1, 4}, 
              {23, 13, 1, 4}, 
              {23, 122, 1, 4},
              {1321, 142, 1, 4},
              {1321, 133,1, 4},
              {3, 16, 0, 5},
              {55, 1003, 0,3},
              {553, 1002, 2, 6},
              {31, 162, 0, 5},
              {7, 1626, 0, 5},
              {7, 2336, 0,5}           
             };


    int riid = 0;
    int pax = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][0] != riid) {
            riid = array[i][0];
            //System.out.print("\n" + riid + "-" + array[i][1]);
        } else {

           // System.out.print("," + array[i][1]);
        }

        if (array[i][2] != pax) {
            pax = array[i][2];
            System.out.print("\n" + riid + "-" + pax + "-" + array[i][1]);
       } else {
          System.out.print("," + array[i][1]);
       }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. It helped. :)